# Expose Graylog Azure VM

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04, graylog2

Bit of a noob question here, but I've been stuck on this for a while. I have an Azure VM running Ubuntu 16.04 that I'm using to run Graylog. I have followed their documentation for the install and configuration, and I'm running the `web_listen_uri` at `127.0.0.1:9000` and the `rest_listen_uri` at `127.0.0.1:12900`, per their suggestion of running the two on different ports.

I've checked the status of the daemon using `service graylog-server status`, and running `curl http://127.0.0.1:9000` on the vm returns the html for the Graylog web interface, so far so good.

I allowed incoming and outgoing traffic on the `9000` port with `iptables`, and the default behavior is `ALLOW`. I understand this is not the best from a security standpoint, but it's a dev appliance and it's on its own vnet, with no Azure cli access (I disabled it after getting the vm configured).

When I created a rule in Azure to allow connections on the VM to 9000, I still can't connect. I added the inbound security rule to a network security group, and the VM's network interface is associated with that nsg. The outbound rule allows port 9000 traffic out to the internet.

My browser is still unable to connect to the vm's public ip address on port 9000. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

So my original hunch was correct, localhost is not externally accessible. After changing `rest_listen_uri = http://0.0.0.0:12900`, `rest_transport_uri = http://my.public.ip.addr:12900`, and `web_listen_uri = http://0.0.0.0:9000`, I'm finally able to connect to the actual website. However, now it's returning that the server for the `rest_transport_uri` is unavailable. If I `curl http://localhost:12900/system/cluster/node` I get nothing back, no timeout, no error, no success. What am I missing from my config?

Comment: I think the problem is that it's on localhost, and that's not externally accessible. I remembered that being a problem when trying to run web apps in docker containers, and they had to be hosted on a non-loopback ip address

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else on here who is struggling with this like I was, I found a good answer here: https://community.graylog.org/t/server-currently-unavailable-error-is-coming-while-trying-to-access-from-browser/503/2

To interpret this, the private ip address corresponds to the network address on `eth0`. This can be found via `ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF; exit}'`. The command here will default to the address that is linked to the external network interface `eth0` without having to explicitly name it. Found that command on another stackoverflow answer.

The public ip address is exactly that, the public ip of the server/vm/machine. This can be found via `curl ifconfig.me`.

To complete this, use `vim server.conf` and add the following:

`rest_listen_uri = http://<your.private.ip.addr>:12900`
`web_listen_uri = http://<your.private.ip.addr>:9000`
`web_endpoint_uri = http://<your.public.ip.addr>:12900`

Save, exit, and use `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart graylog-server.service`, wait for it to restart, then go ahead and login using your browser.